# Checking if divisible with 90+180*n

Tags: php, modulo

I want, in php, to check if $var1 == 90+180*n

Where n is all natural numbers, ie. 1,2,3,4...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I want to check if $var1 is equal to 90, 270, 450... If I used your code 180 would be true.

Comment: Ahhh, I get it. Thank you. Silly me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
$var1 % 180 == 90
```

It's exactly what you need by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) of [modulo operation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the parenthesis to ensure your calculation comes out correctly.

```
if ( $var1 == (90+(180*n) ) )
```

Or just calculate your value before you check it:

```
$checkme = 90 + (80*$n);  
if ( $var1 == $checkme )  {}
```